# Where Can I Find Free Machine Readable Bidirectional Dictionaries?

Tags: translation

I'm hoping to do some playing around with translation and wanted some machine readable bidirectional dictionaries (i.e. English <=> Spanish) to start me off. Something like what comes out of word-reference would be awesome. I know they have an API, but getting something I can use locally would be best. Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to add my 2 cents: the request is about a machine readable dictionary. Obviously, it is meant to be used for programming. Any resources related to programming, such as dictionaries or databases, shouldn't be off topic in stackoverflow. In fact, I found the reply from Eli rather useful. I would therefore like to request that this kind of requests are not eliminated, as they are just as useful as any piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiktionary was pretty great for this and they do daily machine readable dumps. You can get started with [this nifty script written by Matthias Buchmeier](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User%3aMatthias_Buchmeier) that parses the dump for you to give you a very easy to work with bilingual dictionary.

Comment: Hi, im looking for a machine readable dictionary for Tamil-English. Wiktionary doesn't support for Tamil. Are there any other resources that you can recommend me to look into? Would be of great help, thank you!